# python codes can be executed in python mutual environment but not in win7 cmd

Tags: python, web, model-view-controller, flask, windows-7

python codes as following:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    return '<h1>Home</h1>'

@app.route('/signin', methods=['GET'])
def signin_form():
    return '''<form action="/signin" method="post">
              <p><input name="username"></p>
              <p><input name="password" type="password"></p>
              <p><button type="submit">Sign In</button></p>
              </form>'''

@app.route('/signin', methods=['POST'])
def signin():
    if request.form['username']=='admin' and request.form['password']=='password':
        return '<h3>Hello, admin!</h3>'
    return '<h3>Bad username or password.</h3>'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

It can be successfully executed in python mutual environment, but failed to be executed in win7 cmd as a file app.py. 
example1: copy codes and paste into python interactive environment as following:

```
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

example2: copy codes and make them saved as a file named "hsiehapp.py"

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\python file>python hsiehapp.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hsiehapp.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask import Flask
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\flask\__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from jinja2 import Markup, escape
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\jinja2\__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from jinja2.environment import Environment, Template
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\jinja2\environment.py", line 16, in <module>
    from jinja2.defaults import BLOCK_START_STRING, \
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\jinja2\defaults.py", line 32, in <module>
    from jinja2.tests import TESTS as DEFAULT_TESTS
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\sit
e-packages\jinja2\tests.py", line 15, in <module>
    import decimal
  File "C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\dec
imal.py", line 3, in <module>
    from _decimal import *
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Number'
```

My python version is python 3.6.1.
My operation system is windows7.
I am so confused about this, and please help me. 
thank you...

Comment: `AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Number'` this error indicates that there is a `numbers.py ` module in your current directory and it has nothing defined as `Number `  and I think you want to import standard library module `numbers` .

Comment: yes, you are right, thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This error

```
AttributeError: module 'numbers' has no attribute 'Number'
```

indicates that there is a `numbers.py` module in your current directory and it has nothing defined as `Number` and I think you want to import standard library module `numbers`.

Rename that module to something else and then you can use the standard library module.